# Getting Microseconds time from std::chrono::steady_clock::now() since processor power-up

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to get time in Microseconds since processor power up,

I've seen a lot of posts that give time since epoch, but I need time since power-up

Also I am trying to get time a a long int, not as a time_point.

What is the best and the fastest way to convert from time_point to long int.

Lastly, I am not sure what the difference is between boost::steady_clock and std::steady_clock,

Thanks,
-D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a mechanism to get the uptime to microsecond resolution under Linux, but [sysinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html) offers a simple mechanism to retrieve at second resolution:

```
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

struct sysinfo info;
if( sysinfo( &info ) != 0 )
{
    // handle the failure
}

// uptime in seconds is available (as a long) in info.uptime
```

I'm assuming conversion from a `time_point` to a `long` isn't relevant now, but a time point represents a particular point in time, not a length of time elapsed from a reference point. To convert into a number of time units since a starting point, you need to convert it into a duration (by subtracting your starting point) and cast using `duration_cast` to convert to the units of your choice. For example:

```
using namespace std::chrono; // for brevity in the example code.    

auto elapsed = duration_cast<milliseconds>( timepoint1 - reftimepoint ).count()
```

The `boost::steady_clock` is an implementation existing from before the inclusion of `std::steady_clock` in the C++ standard library. Unless you're dealing with an old code base or require portability to compilers or platforms without C++11 support, I don't think you should have much need to use `boost::steady_clock` now.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified the below C function, which you can use in C++ too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct timespec t;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t);
  printf("tv_sec=%llu tv_nsec=%llu\n",
    (unsigned long long)t.tv_sec,
    (unsigned long long)t.tv_nsec);
  return 0;
}
```

When i run the above code comparing with the system uptime, they are almost same.

```
rajg@rajg-LinuxVM:~/Desktop/WinShare$ cat /proc/uptime && ./time
52.46 2.88
tv_sec=52 tv_nsec=468791899

rajg@rajg-LinuxVM:~/Desktop/WinShare$ cat /proc/uptime && ./time
61.08 2.88
tv_sec=61 tv_nsec=81561476

rajg@rajg-LinuxVM:~/Desktop/WinShare$ cat /proc/uptime && ./time
63.97 2.88
tv_sec=63 tv_nsec=979358440

rajg@rajg-LinuxVM:~/Desktop/WinShare$ cat /proc/uptime && ./time
65.05 2.88
tv_sec=65 tv_nsec=52160586

rajg@rajg-LinuxVM:~/Desktop/WinShare$ cat /proc/uptime && ./time
75.44 12.47
tv_sec=75 tv_nsec=448578284
```